# Creating a WebRTC receiver

Tags: webrtc

I am new to WebRTC and trying to figure out how to create a program outside a browser which receives a WebRTC audio stream and outputs it on speakers.
Are there any WebRTC libraries for Java or C#?
That receiver will be running on a linux machine.

--

I've been thinking about using getUserMedia() to access the microphone. But then:
In what format will such a stream be transmitted?
Let's say I use WebRTC2SIP and build a Java endpoint using JSIP;
or I just use a socket and send the stream over http.
What audio format will I get on the receiver side? So far I have read WebRTC does compress the stream somehow.

Comment: If you still need this thing, I think this article will help you a lot: [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

Comment: Thank you. But no, I don't need it any more. But maybe in the future :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there are two ways for you:

1. build the whole WebRTC voice engine for android/iOS or Mac etc., and just use the API provide by VOE.
2. build standalone NS/VAD/AECM/AGC modules and using it in your project. for example, you build standalone NS module for android mobile, you use AudioRecord(java layer, android things) to record sound from MIC, and do the noise suppression process on these data(jni layer, WebRTC things), and finally playback the processed data by using AudioTrack(java layer, android things).

**EDIT:**

1. for the 2nd situation, the format is PCM raw data.

Comment: Thank you. I finally decided to use your second proposition.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the working Audio demo and code at demo.easyrtc.com
The code is all open source and can be checked out at https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc
You can look for any known issues around easyRTC at our forum at 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrtc
Also check out our main site at easyrtc.com

Comment: Thank you! easyRTC is a framework to simplify the access to WebRTC, right? I would like to build an own server/endpoint outside a browser to receive the WebRTC audio stream.

Comment: @DougPelton: I think the OP is asking about using the client API *on the server*, to establish a low-latency client-server connection rather than a connection between peers. Is that something which can be done with easyrtc?

Comment: To receive audio stream at client side you can use easyrtc. But you can not use easyrtc to receive audio stream at server side. For server side you can use https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc [ Note that node-webrtc is not well documented as easyrtc ]. Thanks